# BASH debugging curl

Tags: bash, debugging, curl

I have a bash script that uses curl as follows.

```
curl -d "username=admin" \
     -d "password=password" \
     -d "site=NW3" \
-XPOST "http://localhost/sites/site.cgi"
```

This works fine..  and whilst it is running it outputs its progress to screen.  To hide this I normally amended the command as :

```
curl -s -d "username=admin" \
     -d "password=password" \
     -d "site=NW3" \
-XPOST "http://localhost/sites/site.cgi" > /dev/null
```

and again that works fine.

I'd like to be able to toggle this on or off as needed for debugging. So I thought about calling my script with an additional parameter `debug`

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work :

```
if [ "$1" == "debug" ]; then
  curl=''
  res=''
else
 curl='-s'
 res=' > /dev/null'
fi

curl $curl -d "username=admin" \
     -d "password=password" \
     -d "site=NW3" \
-XPOST "http://localhost/sites/site.cgi" $res
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get this to work ?

Thanks

Comment: I think the command you are looking for is `-v` which means `--verbose`. It will give you more information about the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong is that in bash (like other POSIX shells) an expansion can't be used to change redirection, command line processing has several phases see [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections) for more detail after `$res` expansion `> /dev/null` is split into two arguments `>` literally and `/dev/null`.
a workaround can be to reinterpret command using `eval` but it is not a recommended practice because quotes handling will be harder and may be less safe with arbitrary data, for example a `;` would give a command sequence.

Also it is recommended to use variable expansion between double quotes in a command to avoid glob matching or argument to be split on space or tab.

A better solution may be to change redirection on current shell process

```
if [ "$1" == "debug" ]; then
    curl=( )
    # duplicate fd1 to fd3
    exec 3>&1
else
    curl=( -s )
    # duplicate fd1 to fd3 and redirect fd1 to /dev/null
    exec 3>&1 1>/dev/null
fi

# redirection inherited from current process
curl "${curl[@]}" -d "username=admin" \
    -d "password=password" \
    -d "site=NW3" \
    -XPOST "http://localhost/sites/site.cgi"

# restore redirection (and close fd3)
exec 1>&3 3>&-
```

EDIT: as suggested by @DanielStenberg, `curl` `-o` option can be used instead:

```
if [ "$1" == "debug" ]; then
    curl=( )
    res=( )
else
    curl=( -s )
    res=( -o /dev/null )
fi

# redirection inherited from current process
curl "${curl[@]}" -d "username=admin" \
    -d "password=password" \
    -d "site=NW3" \
    -XPOST "http://localhost/sites/site.cgi" "${res[@]}"
```

Comment: A simpler solution to the original problem would be to use `res=' -o /dev/null'` and use curl's built-in "redirect"...

Comment: How would I use that ?

Comment: @DanielStenberg, thank you, i haven't looked at curl options in that case to respect the enclosing quotes, `res=( -o /dev/null )` and `"${res[@]}"`